# Ruby on Rails how to use submit button with radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

For my final project I need to create two radio buttons with a submit button that will display my GPA for all my classes and those in my major. I can have them displayed easily but am stuck when I need to use radio buttons to display only one

```html
<h2>Please select which GPA you would like to view:</h2>

<%= form_tag("/trans/transcript", :method => "get") do %>
<table>
  <tr>
    
 <th>Major Credits</th>
 <th>All Credits</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
 <td><%= radio_button_tag(:gpa, "Major") %></td>
 <td><%= radio_button_tag(:gpa, "All") %> </td>
  </tr>
  
  
</table>
  <%= submit_tag("View GPA") %>
<% end %>



<p> Major credits GPA  <%= @transcript.GPA_for_major %>
<p> All credits GPA  <%= @transcript.GPA_for_non_major %>
```

Everything appears fine but I'm not sure how to set up the controller to say if he clicks the major gpa radio button and clicks "View GPA" this <%= @transcript.GPA_for_major %>  should display

Comment: Do you want to display the GPA in the same view?

Comment: Yes in the same view is my classes so underneath it is where the radio buttons go

Answer (score 0):

### SHORT ANSWER

- Make an instance variable @gpa in TransController's transcript action
- In the transcript action, check for params[:gpa]

  - set @gpa & @transcript to nil if params[:gpa].nil?
  - set @gpa to params[:gpa] and @transcript accordingly if params[:gpa] is not nil
- In the view/trans/transcript.html.erb

  - If @gpa is nil, display nothing
  - If @gpa == "Major" show @transcript.GPA_for_major
  - If @gpa == "All" show @transcript.GPA_for_non_major

### LONG ANSWER

Assuming that the controller is trans and the action is transcript, here is what you should do in TransController

```
class TransController < ApplicationController

  def transcript
    if params[:gpa].nil?
      @transcript = @gpa = nil
    else
      @gpa = params[:gpa]
      @transcript = ... # Find your transcript here
    end
  end
  # ... other actions
  # ... other actions
  # ... other actions
end
```

and here is how the trans/transcript.html.erb view should look like -

```
<h2>Please select which GPA you would like to view:</h2>
<%= form_tag('trans/transcript', :method => "get") do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Major Credits</th>
      <th>All Credits</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Major<%= radio_button_tag(:gpa, "Major") %></td>
      <td>All<%= radio_button_tag(:gpa, "All") %> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag("View GPA") %>
<% end %>

<% if @gpa == "Major" %>
  <%= @transcript.GPA_for_major %>
<% elsif @gpa == "All" %>
  <%= @transcript.GPA_for_major %>
<% end %>
```